# Siri Window is not in native resolution when connecting external monitor to MBP

Tags: macbook-pro, display, high-sierra, siri

When using Siri on my 2017 MBP running macOS High Sierra, I noticed that the text in the window is not sharp..

[image: Text is not sharp]

The text and image are not sharp and it feels as if low-resolution images/text have been upscaled for Retina size.

---

On trying to find if this was an issue with my display, I disconnected my external monitor and it seems that connecting a Non-Retina external display is causing this.

Here is a side-by-side comparison of the same screen grab once with the display connected and once without.

**No Monitor Connected**

[image: No monitor connected. Text is sharp]

**Monitor Connected**

[image: Monitor Connected]

---

The Siri window is being opened on the laptop display and not the external monitor. My display resolution is unchanged between the 2 scenarios.

I do not have access to a High Dpi external monitor to check if the issue is present in that scenario as well.

Is this a bug? How can I try to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your should try updating the macOS Mojave. If you don't want to for now,

1. Did you try resetting the NVRAM and SMC? https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063
2. Try using Onyx to clean application and system caches and reboot.

Let me know if that works.